# How do I convert jks keystore file to something like PEM?

Tags: openssl, keystore, keytool, jks

I have a JKS keystore with a couple of certicates signed by CA. 
I would like to convert this jks file to PCKS12, however `TrustedCertEntry`s cannot be converted using the Java keytool because they are not supported. How would I convert this jks file to, say, PCKS12 ?

I have looked for similar questions on SO, and this is what I have found:

> > [Convert CA-signed JKS keystore to PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528944/convert-ca-signed-jks-keystore-to-pem)

However, this did not seem to work for me, as the conversion failed at this step

```
C:\Temp>openssl x509 -in exported-der.crt -out exported-pem.crt 
-outform pem -inform der
```

due to this error

> > [...]PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:[...]

because it seems to be encrypted or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try following changes in your command

```
C:\Temp>openssl x509 -in exported-der.crt -out exported-pem.crt -outform PEM -inform DER
```

[Documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html) says `DER|PEM|NET` as valid value, not `pem` or `der`.

Comment: Actually, these are not case-sensitive, so that cannot be the issue.

Comment: From the error message, it tries to read PEM certificate whereas in fact certificate is in DER format.